Having issue with Route53, ec2, Apache Virtual host and wordpress working
I am having wordpress blog - https://blog.pepagora.com, hosted on Amazon aWS EC2 instance and DNS is managed in Route53. Suddenly blog site stopped responding and couldn't figure out why?
For testing purpose i just created one under maintenance HTML file and tried calling that file from browser blog.pepegora.com/maintenance.html even this is not loading.
My Route53 is fine
My Virtual Host (screenshot attached in pic link)
Maintenance HTML File (screenshot attached in pic link)
Browser view (screenshot attached in pic link)
No Error in log (screenshot attached in pic link)
Screen shot link : https://prnt.sc/m5Blq8CsXV-U
What could be the issue? How do i Know my virtual host is correct as i checked DNSWATCH.INFO the A record is correctly pointed
I tried Apachectl comfiest all syntax is OK
https://prnt.sc/_WbtfgB_uHZk

What does your logs show? Does the request hit your server?

No errors in log... Its 0KB..
I think Request is not hitting the server else my maintenance.html page should be displayed in browser now i am getting Not Found

So then the DNS record points at the wrong place, or the resource it points at is not configured correctly.

But when i checked in Route53 it is pointed to correct server IP..
I am perplexed why request is not getting routed properly???
Is there anyidea whr i can get the issue
My PING is going to correct IP address - https://prnt.sc/80jGaVUNpwIb

How have you verified that it's the correct IP?

I checked it in Post man what i am getting.
If i select Options I am getting proper page content - https://prnt.sc/CXOSCAuEGXvE
If i select GET/POST i am geting 404 - https://prnt.sc/ILRi9uBlH02L

Yes IP ADDRESS is correct

Do you have some load balancer or similar in front of the server? To me it seems there's an component somewhere in the path you're unaware of.

No, Load balancer is not there... That is why i am perplexed... It is a straight forward blog.pepagora.com pointed to EC2 instance and in the instance I have created the Virtual host and defined document root..
Also can you check the post man screenshot i have attached.. where GET is not working and OPTIONS are returning me the right page HTML code

Hello Foaks
Any way i can get some insights... My DNS is propagating to Right IP Address but in my apache is not taking the requests !@#!@#!@ weird..

Log packets and see if the traffic hits your server at all? tcpdump may be a good tool. If it doesn't you have to look up details of your infrastructure.
